# Flutter Unable to Retrieve data from database (infinite loading)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to test if I can retrieve data in my database to the fluter app. However, the indicator won't stop reloading and no data is retrieved. The following pics show details:

[image]

[image]

The code I used is like this:

```
///Importing Libraries and Modules
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'MyHome.dart';
import 'NewsFeed.dart';
import 'WebView.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

///Initializing Variables
bool useMaterial3= true;

///Main Function and App Class
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  
);
  runApp(MyApp());
}



class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'myUTAS',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
                       useMaterial3: useMaterial3,
                      ),
      home: const HomePage()
    );
  }
}    

class NoteList extends StatelessWidget {
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Notes"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: db.collection('news-text').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.docs.map((doc) {
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(doc.data()['paragraph']),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope someone can give me tips.

Comment: Your MyApp() widget calls HomePage() but all that is in this question is the NoteList Widget. Not sure if this is problem but calling NoteList widget might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution using [Riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/) would be as follows. It is generally good practice to decouple data sourcing from the UI widgets. For example you can move from Firestore to another data source without changing the UI widgets.

Also using Freezed package will simplify reading/writing json as your data fields increase. The Freezed model classes are generated with:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

main.dart

```
// Flutter imports:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Package imports:
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:yourapp/screen/news_text_screen.dart';

// Project imports:
import 'firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "News Text",
      home: Scaffold(
        body: NewsTextScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

services/news_text_service.dart

```
// Package imports:
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

// Project imports:
import 'package:yourapp/models/news_text.dart';

class NewsTextService {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firebaseFirestore;
  final String newsTextCollection = 'news-text';

  NewsTextService(
    this._firebaseFirestore,
  );

  List<NewsText> _newsTextFromFirebase(QuerySnapshot? snapshot) =>
      snapshot == null
          ? []
          : snapshot.docs.map(
              (DocumentSnapshot document) {
                Map<String, dynamic> data =
                    document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                return NewsText.fromJson(data);
              },
            ).toList();

  Stream<List<NewsText>> newsTexts() => _firebaseFirestore
      .collection(newsTextCollection)
      .snapshots()
      .map(_newsTextFromFirebase);
}
```

providers/news_text_provider.dart

```
// Package imports:
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:yourapp/models/news_text.dart';

// Project imports:
import 'package:yourapp/services/news_text_service.dart';

final firestoreProvider =
    Provider<FirebaseFirestore>((ref) => FirebaseFirestore.instance);

final newsTextServiceProvider =
    Provider<NewsTextService>((ref) => NewsTextService(
          ref.watch(firestoreProvider),
        ));

final newsTextsProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<List<NewsText>>(
    (ref) => ref.watch(newsTextServiceProvider).newsTexts());
```

models/news_text.dart

```
// Package imports:
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'news_text.freezed.dart';
part 'news_text.g.dart';

@Freezed()
class NewsText with _$NewsText {
  factory NewsText({
    required final String paragraph,
  }) = _NewsText;

  factory NewsText.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) =>
      _$NewsTextFromJson(json);
}
```

screens/news_text_screen.dart

```
// Flutter imports:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:yourapp/providers/news_text_provider.dart';

class NewsTextScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const NewsTextScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final newsTexts = ref.watch(newsTextsProvider);

    return newsTexts.when(
      data: (newsTextsList) => ListView.builder(
        itemCount: newsTextsList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text(newsTextsList[index].paragraph);
        },
      ),
      error: (error, stacktrace) {
        return Text(
          error.toString(),
        );
      },
      loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have another question if that's okay. Can I use the same solution to retrieve images from Firebase Storage and display it in the listview? If yes, can you show me how? I will be grateful 

Comment: yes, you can use FirebaseStorage.instance and get the image URL for use in an Image.network.     Future<String> getDownloadURL(String child) async =>
      _firebaseStorage.ref().child(child).getDownloadURL();